# Multiple Line ellipses with class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this code to make multiple line ellipsis,

first I added this code for only one div it was working now but this is not work with many divs

```js
function ellipsizeTextBox(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  var wordArray = el.innerHTML.split(' ');
  while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
    wordArray.pop();
    el.innerHTML = wordArray.join(' ') + '...';
  }
}
ellipsizeTextBox('overflowedDiv');
```

```css
.overflowedDiv {
  height: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<div id="overflowedDiv">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div id="overflowedDiv">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

I don't know what is the problem in my code?Please help.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `id=overflowDiv` on all `div` elements, which is not valid. In addition `getElementById` only returns the first match and not all divs.

Using your existing code, use `class` instead of `id` and in addition use use `getElementsByClassName` to return all matched elements.

Then you can iterate through all elements and apply your logic to each one.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    .overflowedDiv {
      height: 60px;
      width: 400px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top
    }
  </style>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>





  <div class="overflowedDiv">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>

  <div class="overflowedDiv">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>

  <script>
    function ellipsizeTextBox(className) {
      var wordArray;
      var el;
      var els = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
      for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        el = els[i];
        wordArray = el.innerHTML.split(' ');
        while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
          wordArray.pop();
          el.innerHTML = wordArray.join(' ') + '...';
        }
      }
    }
    ellipsizeTextBox('overflowedDiv');
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there any need to add/use `jquery` in above code?

Comment: Not unless your application is already using it or you have issues with different browsers. Check `getElementsByClassName` [**browser compatibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#Browser_compatibility) for details

Answer (score 3):

You can't use same ID for multiple elements, use class instead. and select element by `getElementsByClassName` selector, and class name will return elements in `array` format, use your code in loop.

```js
var _getElements = document.getElementsByClassName('overflowedDiv');
var i = 0;
for (i; i < _getElements.length; i++) {
  var el = _getElements[i];
  var wordArray = el.innerHTML.split(' ');
  while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
    wordArray.pop();
    el.innerHTML = wordArray.join(' ') + '...';
  }
}
```

```css
.overflowedDiv {
  height: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<div class=overflowedDiv>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div class=overflowedDiv>
  In reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div class=overflowedDiv>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```